# Avoid Refreshing page submiting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, form-submit

Whenever using this form that I made (in Portuguese), refreshing removes all previously entered data from the page. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it? Thank you for your time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm(){
            // Initiate Variables With Form Content
            var nome = $("#nome").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var telefone = $("#telefone").val();
            var assunto = $("#assunto").val();
            var mensagem = $("#mensagem").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "send-contact2.php",
                data: "nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email + "&telefone=" + telefone + "&assunto=" + assunto + "&mensagem=" + mensagem,
                cache:false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
</script>

<form id="myForm">
    <div class="col col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required value="" tabindex="1" placeholder="Nome">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required value="" tabindex="2" placeholder="E-mail">
        <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" required value="" tabindex="2" placeholder="Telefone">
        <select id="assunto" name="assunto" required>
            <option value="outros">Outros assuntos</option>
            <option value="encomendas">Encomendas</option>
         </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6">
        <textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" cols="29" rows="8" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-12 ">
        <button name ="submit" type="submit" onclick="return submitForm();">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your function also needs to `return false` to stop the click event behaviour from submitting the form:

```
function submitForm(){
    // your code...
    return false;
}
```

Better still, hook to the `submit` event of the `form` directly and do away with the clunky `onclick` handlers, and use `serialize()` to gather the form data for you:

```
<button name="submit" type="submit">Enviar</button>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "send-contact2.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I agree, but then without the onclick event on the button, but rather the submit event on the form. I wrote the comment while you were editting your post ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `onClick` action to `onSubmit` and add `return false` after method. Like this:

`<button name ="submit" type="submit" onsubmit="submitForm();  return false;">Enviar</button>`

Good practice will be add `method="POST"` to your form attributes.